# How to marge third party code to specific directory

Tags: git

I have third party application hosted on github. The application is divided into two separated repositories. I would like to create my aplication based on third party code but I need to upgrade third party code from time to time.

So I decided to create my own repository. Then I add third party repositories to my repository like this:

```
git remote add [first repo name] [first repo URL]

git remote add [second repo name] [second repo URL]

git fetch [first repo name]

git fetch [second repo name]
```

And I merge third party code with my code like this

```
git merge [first repo name]/[branch name] --squash --allow-unrelated-histories

git merge [second repo name]/[branch name] --squash --allow-unrelated-histories
```

It's works but the third party code have been writing to root directory. I need to move third party code (only for second repository) to another folder (name of the folder is plugins). How to merge third party code to specific directory?

Comment: Will [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) be suitable for your use case?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: I think no, because I want to modify both my own code and third party code. I want not modify third party repository.